# Error: Type 'String!' has no member 'video'

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//start camera

        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let captureDevice =
           AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:
                captureDevice ) else { return }
        captureSession.addInput(input)

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

I get the error in this line at (for: **.video**):

```
AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
```

Comment: This is confusing. `AVCaptureDevice` doesn't exist in AVKit for me in either iOS or macOS. A version does exist in Foundation, but it doesn't have that `default` method, *even though there is documentation for your method*.

Answer (score 5):

Replacing AVMediaType.video with AVMediaTypeVideo worked for me.

Comment: That worked. Xcode also suggests you into replacing `for:` to `forMediaType:`. So that it fully becomes `forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo`. This is all probably due to updates to swift/these apis

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact error when building with "Swift language Version" set to "Swift 3.3".

Changing the swift language version from "3.3" to "4.1" solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
class func `default`(_ deviceType: AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType, 
             for mediaType: AVMediaType?, 
        position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice?
```

Accepts a DeviceType, which can be:

```
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInMicrophone
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTelephotoCamera
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera
AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera
```

Comment: So what exatly do i need to change now? Im sorry im new to swift :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. The documentation I was looking at was for Xcode 9. What you need is first to import `AVFoundation` and then use this function:

```
class func defaultDevice(withDeviceType deviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType!, 
                                         mediaType: String!, 
                                          position: AVCaptureDevicePosition) -> AVCaptureDevice!
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-default?changes=latest_minor

For example:

```
let c = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotCamer,
                                           mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                            position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to convert my project to Swift4. This works for me.

```
device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
```